# Why do I need nonlocal to not get a UnboundLocalError in this leetcode problem?

Tags: python

I'm a JavaScript developer trying to learn Python. I'm doing this leetcode problem, and I'm not sure why I need to add nonlocal to avoid a UnboundLocalError error. In JavaScript, I would have access to the result variable due to closures. Any help would be appreciated.

[Leetcode Problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/range-sum-of-bst/)

My code:

```
class Solution:
    def rangeSumBST(self, root: Optional[TreeNode], low: int, high: int) -> int:
    
        res = 0
        
        def dfs(node):
            nonlocal res
            
            if not node:
                return
            
            if node.val >= low and node.val <= high:
                res += node.val
                
            dfs(node.left)
            dfs(node.right)
            
        dfs(root)
        
        return res
```

Comment: As you assign to `res` somewhere in your function (with +=), it is considered as a  local variable in this function unless declared otherwise. That's the only rule Python applies.

Comment: `Optional` is not defined,  `TreeNode` is not defined...